Hierarchical classification approach to a multiclass problem
Having a multiclass classification task. My goal is to solve this using the Local Classifier per Parent Node (LCPN) approach.
Let me explain using a MWE.
Say I have this dummy dataset:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=5,
                             n_informative=4)

I came up with the distance matrix between these classes to be:
d = np.array(
[[  0.,    201.537, 197.294, 200.823, 194.517],
 [201.537,   0.,    199.449, 202.941, 196.703],
 [197.294, 199.449,   0.,    198.728, 192.354],
 [200.823, 202.941, 198.728,   0.,    195.972],
[[194.517, 196.703, 192.354, 195.972,   0.   ]]
)

So, I determined the class hierarchy like so:
hc = hierarchy.linkage(d, method='complete')

The dendrogram obtained is thus:
dendrogram = hierarchy.dendrogram(hc, labels=['A','B','C', 'D', 'F'])
dendrogram


Which I illustrate in a tree-like structure, using hierarchy.to_tree() as:

My Question:
How do I fit a classifier such as a DecisionTreeClassifier or SVM at each internal node (including the root), following the LCPN method, to proceed as in the tree illustration above?

The PerParentNodeLocalClassifier estimator below works as follows.

A linkage matrix Z is derived from the distance matrix, and represented as a tree
For each parent node in the tree, the classes belonging to the left and right branches are grouped and binarised into 0 (left group) and 1 (right group).
Irrelevant classes for that node are removed, and a classifier is fitted to learn left/right predictions at that node.
We recurse through the tree, fitting a classifier as above for each parent node.

Credit to @NickODell with this answer for the graph recursion code, using graphviz to construct the graph visualisation. I modelled all the recursion routines on this same method.
At inference time, we take one sample at a time and traverse the tree. The classifier at each node is used to determine whether we branch left (0) or right (1).
Some details about the implementation below:

By default the base estimator is a DecisionTreeClassifier. You can specify an alternative classifier using the estimator= parameter.
The estimator computes the class distance matrix during fitting when dissimilarity="euclidean". You can alternatively specify your own distance matrix by setting dissimilarity="precomputed" and then .fit(X, y, dissimilarity_matrix=<precomputed_matrix>).

The implementation is not field-tested, so it's recommended to use the default verbose=1 level and keep plot_figures=True. There's useful summary information there for sanity-checking the estimator's logic. The higher verbosity level verbose=2 reports results on a per-sample basis.
Let's take two test cases; your example data and a more complex case.
Test case 1
Outputs:

                Building leaf assignments dict (0: left, 1:right)                
classifier at parent node 8 
 comprises classes        [1, 3, 0, 2, 4] 
 with cluster assignments [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
classifier at parent node 7 
 comprises classes        [3, 0, 2, 4] 
 with cluster assignments [0, 1, 1, 1]
...

                               Fitting classifiers                               
Fitting node8 classifier using 1000 samples (100% of the data) 
 left group:  [1] (201 samples) 
 right group: [3, 0, 2, 4] (799 samples) 
 imbalance (≥1) ratio: 3.98
Fitting node7 classifier using 799 samples (80% of the data) 
 left group:  [3] (199 samples) 
 right group: [0, 2, 4] (600 samples) 
 imbalance (≥1) ratio: 3.02
...

If we initialise the estimator with verbose=2 we get sample-wise reports, useful for checking individual samples.
clf.verbose = 2
clf.predict(X[:1])

                             Predicting for sample                               
X_i:  [ 0.93065833 -1.10836254 -1.27437476  0.16353084 -0.9043927   0.114701...
 node8 is branching right (1)
 node7 is branching left (0)
 final prediction is encoded class=3 [y=3]

The test data and precomputed distance matrix:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=5, n_informative=4, random_state=0
)

distance_matrix = np.array(
    [[  0.,    201.537, 197.294, 200.823, 194.517],
     [201.537,   0.,    199.449, 202.941, 196.703],
     [197.294, 199.449,   0.,    198.728, 192.354],
     [200.823, 202.941, 198.728,   0.,    195.972],
     [194.517, 196.703, 192.354, 195.972,   0.   ]]
)

Fit and score:
clf = PerParentNodeLocalClassifier(
    dissimilarity='precomputed',
    linkage_method='complete',
    # estimator=LinearSVC() #optionally specify an alternative base classifier
)

clf.fit(X, y, dissimilarity_matrix=distance_matrix)

clf.predict(X_val)
clf.score(X_val, y_val)

Test case 2
A more complex tree structure.

Test data, this time without a precomputed distance matrix:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

n_features = 7
n_classes = 5
X_a, y_a = make_classification(
    n_samples=10_000,
    n_features=n_features, n_informative=5,
    n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=n_classes, random_state=0
)

Usage:
clf = PerParentNodeLocalClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X_a, y_a)

Classifier implementation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, clone, ClassifierMixin, MetaEstimatorMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array, check_X_y, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Pool

class PerParentNodeLocalClassifier (BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin, MetaEstimatorMixin):
    """
    A classifier implementing the "local classifier per parent node" (LCPN) algorithm.
    
    LPCN is a classification algorithm where local classification decisions are
    made over a pre-defined class hierarchy, resulting in a final prediction
    that reflects the hierarchical relationship between classes.
    
    This implementation is a meta-estimator that fits a classifier at each parent
    node. Parent nodes are derived from a class dissimilarity (distance) matrix
    using agglomerative clustering. The class dissimilarity matrix is either
    user-supplied or computed from the data during fitting.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : object, default=None
        The base estimator used for each local classifier. If None, then the
        base estimator is DecisionTreeClassifier initialised with
        `max_depth=5` and `class_weight="balanced"`.
    
    linkage_method : {"single", "complete", "average", "weighted", "centroid",
                      "median", "ward"}, default="single"
        The linkage method used for agglomerative clustering, supplied to
        scipy.hierarchy.linkage().
    
    dissimilarity : {"precomputed", "euclidean"}, default="euclidean"
        If "precomputed", the class dissimilarity (distance) matrix must be
        supplied as `.fit(X, y, dissimilarity_matrix=...)`.
        
        If "euclidean", a dissimilarity matrix will be computed from the data
        during `.fit(X, y)`. In this case, the dissimilarity between each pair
        of classes `(i, j)` is defined as the euclidean distance between their
        centroids in feature space.
    
    verbose : bool or int, default=1
        Controls the verbosity when fitting and predicting. Use 1/True for
        general information, and 2 for per-sample details. 0 or False not
        recommended as this estimator has not been field-tested.
    
    plot_figures : bool, default=True
        If True, two plots will be rendered showing the dendrograms and the
        decision tree. Useful for a visual check of the estimator's classification
        logic. False is not recommended as this estimator has not been field-tested.
    
    n_jobs : int, default=1
        Specifies how many workers to dispatch when predicting. -1 will use
        all CPUs. When set to 1, the samples will be evaluated strictly
        sequentially.
    
    random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, default=None
        Controls the randomness of `estimator`, if applicable.
    """
    def __init__(
        self,
        estimator=None,
        linkage_method='single',
        dissimilarity='euclidean',
        verbose=1,
        plot_figures=True,
        n_jobs=1,
        random_state=None
    ):
        self.estimator = estimator
        self.linkage_method = linkage_method
        self.dissimilarity = dissimilarity
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.plot_figures = plot_figures
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
        self.random_state = random_state
        
    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        """
        Fit the estimator. Optionally takes `dissimilarity_matrix=` parameter.
        
        Parameters:
        X (pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray): Features shaped (n_samples, n_features).
        y (pd.Series, np.ndarray): Multi-class labels (n_samples,).
        
        **kwargs
        dissimilarity_matrix (np.ndarray): Required if `dissimilarity="precomputed"`,
                                           shaped (n_classes, n_classes)
        """
        #Input checks for sklearn estimators
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
                
        #sklearn checks
        if hasattr(X, 'columns'):
            self.feature_names_in_ = np.array(
                X.columns, dtype='object'
            )
        self.n_features_in_ = X.shape[1]
        
        #For simplicity always define a self.label_encoder_
        # It won't make a difference if supplied y is encoded.
        self.label_encoder_ = LabelEncoder().fit(y)
        self.classes_original_ = self.label_encoder_.classes_
        self.n_classes = len(self.classes_original_)
        
        #encoded values are used for all computations
        self.classes_ = self.label_encoder_.transform(self.classes_original_)
        
        if self.verbose:
            print(
                f'\nSupplied classes', self.classes_original_, 'encoded to',
                str(self.classes_),
                '\nFigures display encoded values. Predictions returned in original format.'
            )
        
        self.X = X
        self.y = self.label_encoder_.transform(y)
        
        #Handle dissimilarity= param
        # creates self.dissimilarity_matrix_
        self.handle_dissimilarity_arg(kwargs)
        if self.verbose:
            matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(
                self.dissimilarity_matrix_,
                index=[i for i in self.classes_],
                columns=[i for i in self.classes_]
            ).rename_axis(columns='class')
            
            display(
                matrix_df
                .style
                .set_caption(self.dissimilarity + ' dissimilarity matrix')
            )
        
        #Create linkage matrix
        # creates self.Z_ and self._df_
        self.create_linkage_matrix()
        if self.verbose:
            display(
                self.Z_df_
                .style
                .set_caption('linkage matrix Z')
                .background_gradient(subset='linkage_distance', cmap='plasma')
            )
        if self.plot_figures:
            self.plot_dendrogram()
        
        #Linkage matrix as tree
        self.root_node_ = hierarchy.to_tree(self.Z_)
        if self.plot_figures:
            self.render_tree_visualisation()
        
        #Leaf assignments
        self.leaf_assignments_dict = {}
        self.build_leaf_assignments_dict_recursive(
            self.root_node_,
            self.leaf_assignments_dict
        )
        
        #Fit classifiers
        self.classifiers_dict_ = {}
        
        if self.estimator is None:
            self.estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(
                max_depth=5,
                class_weight='balanced',
            )
            
            if self.verbose:
                print('\nUsing default base estimator:\n', self.estimator)
        
        if hasattr(self.estimator, 'random_state'):
            self.estimator.set_params(**{'random_state': self.random_state})
            
        self.fit_classifier_tree_recursive(self.root_node_, self.classifiers_dict_)
        
        return self
    
    def predict(self, X):
        """
        Render a prediction for each sample.
        """
        check_is_fitted(self)
        
        X = check_array(X)
        
        if not self.n_jobs:
            raise ValueError('n_jobs must be a non-zero integer')
        
        #Strictly sequential evaluation is useful for debugging
        if self.n_jobs == 1:
            predictions = []
            print()
            for i, sample in enumerate(X):
                if self.verbose:
                    print(
                        f'Rendering prediction for sample',
                        f'{i+1:>5d} of {len(X):>5d} [{(i+1) / len(X):>5.1%}]...',
                        end='\r' if i + 1 != len(X) else 'done\n',
                    )
                predictions.append( self.predict_sample(sample) )
            
        else:
            n_jobs = self.n_jobs if self.n_jobs > 0 else self.n_jobs + cpu_count() + 1
            if self.verbose:
                print(f'\n Predicting using {n_jobs} CPUs')
            
            with Pool(n_jobs) as p:
                predictions = p.map(self.predict_sample, X)
        
        return self.label_encoder_.inverse_transform(predictions)
    
    #
    # Helper methods
    #
    
    def handle_dissimilarity_arg(self, fit_kwargs):
        """
        Sets the dissimilarity matrix.
        
        Either compute it from Xy if dissimilariy="euclidean",
        or use dissimilarity_matrix supplied to
        .fit() when dissimilarity='precomputed'.
        
        """
        if self.dissimilarity == 'euclidean':
            self.dissimilarity_matrix_ = self.compute_euclidean_class_dissimilarity_matrix()
        elif self.dissimilarity == 'precomputed':
            if 'dissimilarity_matrix' not in fit_kwargs:
                raise TypeError(
                    ".fit() requires 'dissimilarity_matrix=' argument "
                    "when dissimilarity='precomputed'"
                )
            
            dissimilarity_matrix = fit_kwargs['dissimilarity_matrix']
                
            self.dissimilarity_matrix_ = self.sanitise_dissimilarity_matrix(
                dissimilarity_matrix
            )
            
    def compute_euclidean_class_dissimilarity_matrix(self):
        """
        Computes (n_classes, n_classes) dissimilarity (distance) matrix
        using the euclidean distance between pairs of classes in feature space.
        """
        class_centroids = np.stack(
            [self.X[self.y==klass].mean(axis=0) for klass in self.classes_],
            axis=0
        )
        
        dissimilarity_matrix = np.array([
            [np.linalg.norm(class_centroids[i] - class_centroids[j]) for j in self.classes_]
            for i in self.classes_
        ]).reshape(self.n_classes, self.n_classes)
        
        return self.sanitise_dissimilarity_matrix(dissimilarity_matrix)


    def sanitise_dissimilarity_matrix(self, mtx):
        """
        Checks if the supplied matrix is symmetrical and has a zero diagonal.
        If not, it forces those conditions on the matrix.
        """
        if np.array_equal(mtx, mtx.T) and np.abs(mtx).trace()==0.:
            return mtx
        
        if self.verbose:
            print(
                '\nDissimilarity matrix is either asymmetrical or has '
                'non-zero diagonal. Coercing matrix for symmetry and diagonal=0.'
            )
        
        #Enforce symmetry, diag=0
        np.fill_diagonal(
            mtx_clean := (mtx + mtx.T) / 2,
            val=0
        )
        return mtx_clean

    
    def create_linkage_matrix(self):
        """
        Uses scipy to create the linkage matrix Z, and a DataFrame version as well.
        """
        self.Z_ = hierarchy.linkage(
            squareform(self.dissimilarity_matrix_),
            method=self.linkage_method,
        )
        
        self.Z_df_ = pd.DataFrame({
            'class_i': self.Z_[:, 0].astype(int),
            'class_j': self.Z_[:, 1].astype(int),
            'linkage_distance': self.Z_[:, 2],
            'total_members': self.Z_[:, 3].astype(int)
        }).rename_axis(index='step')
    
    
    def plot_dendrogram(self):
        """
        Uses scipy to draw a dendrogram for each link point.
        """
        f, axs = plt.subplots(
            nrows=1, ncols=len(self.Z_df_), figsize=(11, 3),
            sharey=True, layout='constrained'
        )
        
        for ax, cut_pt in zip(axs, self.Z_df_.linkage_distance):
            dendrogram = hierarchy.dendrogram(
                self.Z_,
                leaf_font_size=10,
                labels=self.classes_,
                color_threshold=cut_pt,
                above_threshold_color='darkslategray',
                ax=ax
            )
            ax.axhline(cut_pt, linewidth=1.5, color='deeppink', linestyle=':')
            ax.spines[['top', 'right', 'bottom']].set_visible(False)
            ax.set_title(f'linkage step {np.argwhere(ax==axs).item()}')
        #Formatting
        ax = axs[0]
        ax.set_xlabel('class')
        ax.spines.left.set_visible(True)
        ax.set_ylabel(self.linkage_method + ' linkage distance')
    
    def render_tree_visualisation(self):
        """
        Uses graphviz package to display the linkage matrix as a tree
        """
        try:
            import graphviz
        except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
            print(
                'Error importing graphiz package. '
                'graphviz package is required for tree visualisation.\n', e
            )
            return
        
        try:
            dot = graphviz.Digraph('cluster_heirarchy')
            self.render_dot_tree_recursive(self.root_node_, dot)
            display(dot)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error rendering graph visualisation using graphviz\n', e)
            
            
    def render_dot_tree_recursive(self, node, dot, parent=None):
        if node.is_leaf():
            dot.node(f"node{node.id}", f'class {node.id}')
        
        if parent:
            dot.edge(f"node{parent.id}", f"node{node.id}")
        if node.left:
            self.render_dot_tree_recursive(node.left, dot, node)
        if node.right:
            self.render_dot_tree_recursive(node.right, dot, node)
        
        
    #Build classifier tree
    def build_leaf_assignments_dict_recursive(self, node, res_dict, parent=None):
        """
        Recursively populates a dictionary that identifies each parent node with
        its class members.
        """
        if node.is_leaf():
            return
        
        # 0 2 4 1 3 relevant members, left-right
        # 0 1 0 1 1 assignments for [y0 y1 y2 y3 y4]
        #assignments[lr membs] = relevant assignments, l-r order
        leaves_lr = np.array(node.pre_order())
        assignments_lr = hierarchy.cut_tree(self.Z_, height=node.dist).ravel()[leaves_lr]
        
        #Convert left to 0, right  as 1
        assignments_lr = (assignments_lr - assignments_lr[0]).astype(bool).astype(int)
        
        res_dict[node.id] = [leaves_lr, assignments_lr]
        
        if self.verbose:
            if parent is None:
                print('\n', 'Building leaf assignments dict (0: left, 1:right)'.center(80, ' '))
            print(
                'classifier at parent node', node.id,
                '\n comprises classes       ', leaves_lr.tolist(),
                '\n with cluster assignments', assignments_lr.tolist(),
            )
        
        self.build_leaf_assignments_dict_recursive(node.left, res_dict, node)
        self.build_leaf_assignments_dict_recursive(node.right, res_dict, node)
    
    
    def fit_classifier_tree_recursive(self, node, clf_dict, parent=None):
        """
        Fit a classifier at each parent node, and populate a dict with the
        classifiers.
        """
        if node.is_leaf():
            return
        
        #leaves relevant to this node, and their assignments
        leaves, assignments = self.leaf_assignments_dict[node.id]
        
        #discard samples with irrelevant leaves
        subset_ixs_bool = np.isin(self.y, leaves)
        X_subset, y_subset = [arr[subset_ixs_bool] for arr in [self.X, self.y]]
        
        #group of left classes, and right classes
        # use to binarise y as 0:left group, 1:right group
        left_group, right_group = [leaves[assignments==i] for i in [0, 1]]
        y_bin = np.where(np.isin(y_subset, left_group), 0, 1)
        
        #Fit a classifer for this node
        clf = clone(self.estimator)

        if self.verbose:
            if not parent:
                print('\n', 'Fitting classifiers'.center(80, ' '))
                
            nsamples_left, nsamples_right = [sum(y_bin==i) for i in [0, 1]]
            imbalance_ratio = (
                max(nsamples_left, nsamples_right) / min(nsamples_left, nsamples_right)
            )
            print(
                f'Fitting node{node.id} classifier using {y_bin.size} samples',
                f'({y_bin.size / self.y.size:.0%} of the data)',
                
                f'\n left group:  {left_group.tolist()} ({nsamples_left} samples)',
                f'\n right group: {right_group.tolist()} ({nsamples_right} samples)',
                f'\n imbalance (≥1) ratio: {imbalance_ratio:>4.2f}',
            )

        clf.fit(X_subset, y_bin)
        clf_dict[node.id] = clf
        
        #recurse into child nodes
        self.fit_classifier_tree_recursive(node.left, clf_dict, node)
        self.fit_classifier_tree_recursive(node.right, clf_dict, node)
    
    
    def predict_sample(self, sample):
        """
        Prediction for a single sample.
        """
        if self.verbose == 2:
            print(
                '\n', 'Predicting for sample'.center(80, ' '),
                '\nX_i: ', str(sample)[:70] + '...',
            )
            
        if sample.ndim == 1:
            sample = sample.reshape(1, -1)
        
        prediction = [None] #recursion will deposit value in prediction[0]
        self.predict_sample_recursive(sample, prediction, self.root_node_)
        return prediction[0]
        
    def predict_sample_recursive(self, sample, return_value_placeholder, node, parent=None):
        if sample.ndim == 1:
            sample = sample.reshape(1, -1)
        
        if self.verbose == 2:        
            if node.is_leaf():
                print(
                    f' final prediction is encoded class={node.id}',
                    f'[y={self.label_encoder_.inverse_transform([node.id]).item()}]'
                )

        #Reached leaf node/final prediction
        if node.is_leaf():
            return_value_placeholder[0] = node.id
            return
        
        #Get left/right prediction at this node
        prediction = self.classifiers_dict_[node.id].predict(sample).item()
        if self.verbose == 2:
            print(f' node{node.id}', 'is branching', ['left (0)', 'right (1)'][prediction])
        
        #Recurse into the left/right branch depending on "prediction"
        self.predict_sample_recursive(
            sample,
            return_value_placeholder,
            [node.left, node.right][prediction],
            parent=node
        )


from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# Assuming `X` and `y` are your data and labels respectively
# And `internal_nodes` is a list of internal nodes in the hierarchy

classifiers = {}  # To store classifiers for each internal node

for node in internal_nodes:
    # Implement logic to get samples for classes under the current node
    X_node, y_node = get_samples_for_node(node, X, y)
    
    # Train classifier
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf.fit(X_node, y_node)
    
    classifiers[node] = clf

# Implement `get_samples_for_node` to return samples for the given node


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

On approach I can think of is to modify your labels y. So you set all labels which are not class B to some new class label, let's say G. Then you train a binary classifier to predict either B or G. You collect all samples predicted as class B and remove them from your set.
Then taking this new set, repeat the previous approach, except keeping all class D labels as they were, and setting all others to the new class G.
Some basic pseudocode:
# Split data into train/test
# Optional I guess, but I added it for completeness
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = sklearn.train_test_split(X, y)

# Relabel your data
current_label = 'B'
y_train = [0 if i == curent_label else 1 for i in y_train]
y_test = [0 if i == current_label else 1 for i in y_test]

# Create and fit your classifier
clf = sklearn.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions
y_pred = clf.predict(X_train)

# Index of samples predicted as class G
class_g_pred = np.array([i if v != 0 for i, v in enumerate(y_pred)])

# Remove the B samples from your train set
X_train_new = X_train[class_g_pred]
y_train_new = y_train[class_g_pred]

X_train = X_train_new
y_trian = y_train_new

# Repeat from the top
# Modify your labels now keeping D labels and setting others to G
# Create a new classifier

You can also do all the steps in a loop, so you don't need to hard code each step (good if you want to add more classes/layers later on, and for running your test data as well).
Splitting your data into train and test, isn't something you need to repeat at each step, rather just once at the start.
Something else to consider, is that you are turning each classification task into an imbalanced classification task. If each class has 100 samples, your B vs G classifier will now have 100 samples in class B and 400 in G, which can be harder to fit a model too in some cases.

Not a good solution as proposed by the OP. Class hierarchy may change every time you train the initial classifier to learn hierarchy. By this solution, you must modify the it every time you changed the base classifier.
